# Is it possible to run multiple-shard on multiple remote instance without relica set?

Tags: mongodb

I am using 64-bit MongodbV2.0 on centos and i have created a sharding setup in single instance consists of 2shards,1configsserver,1mongos. This seems to be works fine.When i placed 1shards,1configserver and 1mongos each of the components on three instances ie(Three machines).The data not gets split into other shards only storing on the first shard. My concern is, the set-up i have created is a valid one? If so, without-replica set is it possible to create sharding setup?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

Sharding and replicasets are two distincts feature which can work separatly and together.

Your conf seems ok, have you configured sharding ? (run commands addShard, enablesharding and shardcollection ?)

Comment: Hi @kamaradclimber, Thanks for ur reply.I have enclosed the Three-shard configuration for your kind reference. Please check it out and let me know if i gone wrong.

Comment: FIrst-shard:-                                                 ./mongo First-machine:27017/admin                                  use admin                                                   db.runCommand( { addshard : "firstmachine:10000", maxSize:1/*MB*/ } );db.runCommand( { addshard : "Second-machine:10001", maxSize:1/*MB*/} );                                     db.runCommand( { addshard : "Third-machine:10002" } ); db.runCommand( { enablesharding : "sgserver" } ); db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "sgserver.block_seek_pos", key : {fileGUID : 1} } );

Comment: Second-shard:-                                                 ./mongo First-machine:27017/admin                                  use admin                                                   db.runCommand( { addshard : "firstmachine:10000", maxSize:1/*MB*/ } );db.runCommand( { addshard : "Second-machine:10001", maxSize:1/*MB*/} );                                     db.runCommand( { addshard : "Third-machine:10002" } ); db.runCommand( { enablesharding : "sgserver" } ); db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "sgserver.block_seek_pos", key : {fileGUID : 1} } );

Comment: Thirdshard:-                                                       ./mongo First-machine:27017/admin                                 use admin db.runCommand( { addshard : "firstmachine:10000", maxSize:1/*MB*/ } ); db.runCommand( { addshard : "Second-machine:10001", maxSize:1/*MB*/} );                    db.runCommand( { addshard : "Third-machine:10002" } ); db.runCommand( { enablesharding : "sgserver" } ); db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "sgserver.block_seek_pos", key : {fileGUID : 1} } );

Comment: you don't have to make the operations three times !

Comment: just connect to the mongos (routeur), type the three addShard commands and then enablesharding, shardcollection once.

Comment: Hi, @kamaradclimber, As per your suggestion,I will connect to the mongos (routeur), type the three addShard commands and then enablesharding, shardcollection once. Is it enough to run mongos on each machine? or should i have to connect all three mongos from the first-machine like this?[./mongos --configdb first-machine:27019,Second-machine:27019,Third-machine:27019].Please let me know. Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: You have to run only one mongos. You should really read the documentation about sharding.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have read the documentation but it was not clear over there. So i desire your help. you said that i have to run only one mongos. Its clear. So no need to run mongos on each machine?. Kindly please let me know.

Comment: no you need at least one mongos per cluster. You can add as many as you want even if unnecessary

Comment: Hi @kamaradclimber, Confessed your suggestion. Your help is desperately appreciated.Thanks once again.

Comment: No, I have ended the Discussion. Thanks for your suggestion.